is programSubscribe filtering with multiple accounts possible?
so I am wanting to listen to multiple token account  token balances. I am currently using programSubscribe with filter on the token account owner:
     jsonrpc: "2.0",
     id: 1,
     method: "programSubscribe",
     params: [
       "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
       {
         encoding: "jsonParsed",
         //  commitment: "finalized",
         filters: [
           {
             memcmp: {
               offset: 32, 
               bytes: new PublicKey(
                 "83v8iPyZihDEjDdY8RdZddyZNyUtXngz69Lgo9Kt5d6d"
               ), // base58 encoded string
             },
           },
         ],
       },
     ],

This example is for Orca SOL/USDC Market - 83v8iPyZihDEjDdY8RdZddyZNyUtXngz69Lgo9Kt5d6d.
But my goal is to listen to multiple accounts like that (20+). And instead of sending a new subscription for every account is it possible to just add multiple different accounts in the filters section?

The parameters in the programSubscribe endpoint at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/programsubscribe#parameters make it clear that the returned account must meet all filter criteria.
If you want to subscribe to multiple accounts, you'll either need multiple subscriptions or a single filter that catches more accounts. The filter you've done already will catch all accounts owned by 83v8iPyZihDEjDdY8RdZddyZNyUtXngz69Lgo9Kt5d6d, so that's already a good start. You might want look into the Orca structures to see if you can get a subscription on one of their accounts.
